# ¿Cómo agregar un boton en un JTable?

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica

Quisiera saber cómo agregar un boton (eliminar) que al momento que le dé click al botón agregar, en la celda de una fila se agregue el botón eliminar y así aparezca sucesivamente cada vez que le doy click al boton agregar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! te recomiendo que pegues el codigo, en vez de la imagen porque si alguna vez esta desaparece, esta pregunta no puede ser entendida. Puedes formatear el codigo para que tenga colores e identación usando `ctrl + k `

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, primero te dejaré como hacer el botón y además te proporciono un [link](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f45/agregar-jbutton-jtable-624365/), en donde explican como agregar el botón a la tabla.

```
JButton boton = new JButton("Eliminar");
boton.setSize(100,45);
boton.setVisible(true);
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){ 
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
     tuMetodo(); //lo declaras en otra parte del documento
   }         
};
boton.addActionListener(listener);
```